# perl regex replace non word characters except for ::

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to have some perl regex to replace any non-word characters like so:

```
s/\W//g;
```

However, if there are two colons following eachother like `::`, I would not like to replace those. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: What if there are 3 colons?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/\W/` is `/[^\w]/`, so `/[^\w:]/` would delete every non-word char except colons.

You also want to delete lone colons (`/(?<!:):(?!:)/`), so the final solution is

```
s/[^\w:]|(?<!:):(?!:)//g;
```